# Representation of Analytic function in upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function in a region containing　the upper-plane and the $x$-axis.

Suppose $f$ converges to $0$ uniformly, when $|z|\to\infty$.

**Q**:

1) For any $y>0$, how to show that 
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{\pi i}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\xi-x}{(\xi-x)^2+y^2}f(\xi)d\xi。$$

2) How to use $u(\xi,0)$ to represent $f(z)$, where $f(z)=u(z)+i v(z)$.

*PS*:

For the 1) question, it seems that we consider the integral $f(\xi)(\frac{1}{\xi-z}+\frac{1}{\xi -\bar{z}})$ on the upper semi-circle with large radius, and then let the radius goes to infinity.

But, it should be $f(z)+f(\bar{z})$, I am confused.

Comment: Is $f$ holomorphic on an open set containing the closed upper half plane?

Comment: @zhw. Yes. You are right.

Comment: It would be good to make that clear in your statement.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks for your attention, do you have any idea, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

For the question 1)

---

Let $C_r=[-r,r] \cup \{ |z| = r, \Im(z) > 0\}$ the upper-semicircle of radius $r$. The Cauchy integral formula gives for $|z| < r, \Im(z) >0$ : 
$$f(z) = \frac{1}{2i \pi} \int_{C_r} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds$$
The assumption is that $|f(s)| \le g(|s|)$ which means $$\left|\int_{|s| = r, \Im(s) >0} \frac{f(s)}{s-z}ds\right| = \left|\int_{t=0}^\pi \frac{f(re^{it})}{re^{it}-z}d(re^{it})\right| \le \int_0^\pi \ldots$$

---

For the question 2) I would look at the [Schwartz integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_integral_formula), starting with the case $f$ real on the real axis.

Comment: But it is different to the formula given above.

Comment: @DLIN Start assuming $f$ is real on the real axis. What do you get ?